# In SQL Server, How Do I Select All the Things From Another Table's Matching *TWO* Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

*NOTE: If you can find a better way to title this question, please edit it.  This was a hard one to put into words.*

So Assuming a table of Stuff with the following columns:

```
Stuff
=====
Id, Col1ThingId, Col2ThingId,
```

And the related table of Things

```
Things
======
Id, Name, Rank, Whatever
```

I want to retrieve all the Things that match *either* Col1ThingId or Col2ThingId.  I can select the Stuffs that have the Ids:

```
SELECT Col1ThingId, Col2ThingId
FROM STUFF
WHERE Id = 15
```

Which gives me this result:

```
Col1ThingId Col2ThingId
41472       41474
41510       41512
41513       41515
```

So I'm trying to get all six of these Things.  Something like:

```
Select *
from Things 
where Id "is contained in either column of" {
   select Col1ThingId, Col2ThingId 
   from Stuff
   where Id  = 15
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. You can easily add a second join predicate here.

```
select *
from Things t
join Stuff s on s.Col1ThingId = t.Id or s.Col2ThingId = t.Id
where s.Id = 15
```

Comment: Yeah, my SQL is remedial at best; I don't know how to think in SQL yet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from Stuff s
join Things t on t.id in (s.Col1ThingId, s.Col2ThingId)
where s.Id = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col1ThingId
FROM STUFF
WHERE Id = 15
UNION
SELECT Col2ThingId
FROM STUFF
WHERE Id = 15;
```

Comment: That gets all the ThingId's as a single result, but how do I wrap that with the SELECT to get the Things?

Comment: Inner join that result with Things on Id.